# Law of large numbers and Central Limit Theorem for eigenvalues of perturbed matrices

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, probability-distributions, random-matrices

I'm looking for results where perturbation by iid random entries to a matrix will result in convergence of the eigenvalues to the original eigenvalues. More precisely,

Let $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, M_n$ be a sequence of random matrices ("signal"). Let $E_n$ be an $n \times n$ "error/noise matrix", so that:

(1) $E_n$ and $M$ are independent.
(2) $({E_n})_{ij}$ are iid entries of $E_n$ mean $0$, variance $\sigma^2$.

Now let $n \to \infty.$ One would perhaps expect that under certain conditions on $M_n, E_n$, the asymptotic effect of adding iid errors will vanish.The results I'm looking for will be law of large numbers and CLT for the differences eigenvalues of $M_n + E_n$ and those of $M_n$. For example, are the following true?

(1) *(Law of large numbers)* For each fixed $i,|\lambda_i(M_n + E_n) - \lambda_i(M_n)| \to 0$, either in probability or a.s.

(2) *(CLT)* For each fixed $i, \sqrt{n}(\lambda_i(M_n + E_n) - \lambda_i(M_n))\to \mathcal{N}$ where $\mathcal{N}$ is a normal distribution with mean $0$ and an appropriate variance.

Comment: both statements are true in the bulk of the spectrum (away from the edge), where because of level repulsion, the effect of a perturbation on an individual eigenvalue is a random shift $\delta\lambda$ of the order of the level spacing, so of order $1/\sqrt n$; they are not true near the spectral edge, where the level spacing decreases more slowly than $1/\sqrt n$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you, could you please point me to the corresponding mathematics paper(s) that proves these claims? Also, what's the mathematical definition of "level replusion" ? Thanks again!

Comment: the framework in which to study the effect of a perturbation on an eigenvalue is [Dyson's Brownian motion](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/dyson-brownian-motion/); "level repulsion" is the statement that the random walk which the eigenvalues execute upon increasing the perturbation is that of a set of $n$ particles on a line with a pairwise repulsive interaction potential of the form $-\log|\lambda_i-\lambda_j|$.